# Python matplotlib Plot Line2D object with animation package

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to animate a list of Line2D sets, the problem is I am appending plt.plot(xx) to an array due to an if then else loop and I need this kind of distiguishing due to my results I want to look at.

It works fine If I save every timestep as figure, but it is not working for animation.

Maybe you can give me a hint, here is my code:

```
fig2=plt.figure()      
for t in range(nt+1):
    print('Calculating Timestep '+str(t))
    flowfield=u[:,:,t]
    for i in (x_indices):            
        for j in (y_indices):                    
            if flowfield[i,j]==trigs_n:
               frame_sensor=plt.plot(i, j,'r*' ,c='r',marker='s',markersize=5,label='1')
            elif flowfield[i,j]>=trigs_p:                 
               frame_sensor=plt.plot(i, j, 'g*' ,c='g',marker='s',markersize=5,label='1')
            else:
               frame_sensor=plt.plot(i, j,'k*',markerfacecolor='white',markeredgecolor='white',marker='s',markersize=5,label='0')

    frames_sensor.append([frame_sensor])

anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig2,frames_sensor,interval=50,blit=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to animate lines is to call a series of plots, return the line objects and use animate to update these based on new data. You can do this for as many lines as you want (and the if statement doesn't make a difference). As a minimal example to animate multiple lines based on an if condition,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def init():
    l1, = plt.plot([], [], 'r*-')
    l2, = plt.plot([], [], 'b*-')
    l3, = plt.plot([], [], 'g*-')

    return l1, l2, l3

def update_line(num):
    #Setup some dummy data based on num
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)

    #Some if then else condition to decide which line to update
    if num%3:
        y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * num))
        l1.set_data(x, y1)
    elif num%2:
        y2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * num*0.2))
        l2.set_data(x, y2)
    else:
        y3 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * num*0.3))
        l3.set_data(x,y3)

    return l1, l2, l3

#setup figure
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))

#Setup three different line objects
l1, = plt.plot([], [], 'r*-')
l2, = plt.plot([], [], 'b*-')
l3, = plt.plot([], [], 'g*-')

#Animate calls update line with num incremented by one each time
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, init_func=init,
                                    interval=50, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

This generate the data based on current animation iteration `num`, which can be used as an array index if you already have the data.